# How to create a complex custom progress indicator in React-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-component

I am new to `react native` and I am currently trying to create this progress indicator 
[image]

I couldn't find any good ressource to achieve this result.

Can you guys provide any guidance with this?

Comment: you can create a bunch of colored `View`s, or use react-native-svg to draw shapes

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slider

Comment: @Max I thought about that but I wanted a way to render this specific design but to also inherite the methods of the regular progressBar like `progress`, etc.

Comment: @MayankPandav Thank you, but I want the design I added in the description.

Comment: @Amine I don't see any problem with that, component you create can have any methods and props you want

Comment: @Max Thank you, I will try with this approach and get back with results :)